# Optimising a query that uses index merge by intersection

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, mysql-8.0

I have a MySQL 8 database table `accounts` that has the following columns:

- id (primary)
- city_id (foreign key)
- province_id (foreign key)
- country_id (foreign key)
- school_id (foreign key)
- age (indexed)

**EDIT**: See bottom for complete table structure.

Now, imagine the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(`id`) AS AGGREGATE
FROM
    `accounts`
WHERE
    `city_id` = 1
AND 
    `country_id` = 7
AND 
    `age` = 3
```

At 1 million records, this query becomes slow (~200ms).

When running `EXPLAIN`, I receive the following output:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | accounts | NULL | index_merge | accounts_city_id_foreign accounts_country_id_foreign accounts_age_index | accounts_city_id_foreign accounts_country_id_foreign accounts_age_index | 9,2,9 | NULL | 15542 | 100.00 | Using intersect(accounts_city_id_foreign, accounts_country_id_foreign, accounts_age_index); Using where; Using index |

Given that MySQL appears to be using the indexes, I'm not sure what I can do to bring the execution time down. Does anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT**: In the future, the table will include more columns that will make it impossible to use a composite index as it will exceed the 16 column limit.

**EDIT**: Here's the complete table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `city_id` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `school_id` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_id` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `province_id` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` tinyint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `accounts_city_id_foreign` (`city_id`),
  KEY `accounts_school_id_foreign` (`school_id`),
  KEY `accounts_country_id_foreign` (`country_id`),
  KEY `accounts_province_id_foreign` (`province_id`),
  KEY `accounts_age_index` (`age`),
  CONSTRAINT `accounts_city_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`city_id`) REFERENCES `cities` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `accounts_country_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `countries` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `accounts_province_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`province_id`) REFERENCES `provinces` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `accounts_school_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`school_id`) REFERENCES `schools` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1000002 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Comment: That seems like a bad design. Country id an province id may depend on city id and all of them depend on scool id, so you maybe don't need so many columns

Comment: "In the future, the table will include more columns that will make it impossible to use a composite index as it will exceed the 16 column limit." - you don't need a composite index on more than 16 columns.

Comment: @symcbean Are you suggesting creating a few compound indexes that include several columns e.g. a location composite formed from city, province and country, another for columns x, y and z etc.??

Comment: When you ask a query-optimization question, you should include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <name>` so we don't have to guess at your current columns, data types, indexes, or constraints. Help us to help you!

Comment: @BillKarwin Apologies. I've added the table structure.

Comment: Yes. But I can't tell you exactly what columns based on the information you've provided here. It really depends on *all* the queries that get run on the data.

Comment: @BillKarwin I'm sorry, but I'm not following you... I won't know every possible query combination ahead of time.

Comment: When you ask a query-optimization question on Stack Overflow, we can only give advice for the query (or queries) that you do show. We can't know what other queries you might run, currently or in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes are to help your querying.  So as suggested by Marko and agreed by others, having an index on (city_id, country_id, age) should significantly help.  Now, yes, you will add other columns to the table, but are you trying to filter on 16+ criteria???  I doubt it.  And of the queries you would be running, even if you have multiple composite indexes to help optimize those queries, how many columns might you need at any single time?  4, 5,  6?  After that, I mean how granular do you plan on getting with your data.  Country, State/Province, City, Town, Village, Neighborhood, Street, House? and by the time you are that low in the data, you would be at the page level data anyhow, wouldn't you?

So, your query of Country = 7, that already chops off a ton of stuff.  Then to a given city within that country?  Great, now you are at a finite level.

if you are going do be doing queries against large data that requires any aggregations, and the data is rather fixed from a historical perspective, maybe having pre-aggregated tables by some common elements might help long term.

**FEEDBACK**

The performance of querying is not necessarily where you will be hit, it would be in the inserts, updates, deletes as whatever may change has to update all the indexes on the table - single or composite.  If you are getting more than 5 columns in an index, ask yourself, really??? How granular is it that you need for the index to be optimized.  Querying out the data should be very fast with proper indexes.  Updating indexes is also quick, but if you are dealing with millions of inserts in a month, quarter, year?  The user doing theirs may have a slight delay ( 1/4 second?) but adding up a million seconds starts to get delay. But again, over what period of time would insert/update/delete be done anyhow.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer! To answer your question, it is probably unlikely we'd be doing 16 separate filters. Maybe something like city_id = 1 OR 2, but that's all.

I will follow your suggestion (and that of others) and create a few composite indexes containing related columns e.g. city, province and country. 

Just curious, is there a limit I should be aiming for e.g. no more than X composite indexes before performance is likely to suffer?

Thanks so much!

Comment: @Matt, see revised answer vs comment

Comment: Thanks for the extra feedback. Very valuable!

Answer (score 3):

Try creating a composite index on all three columns, e.g. `CREATE INDEX idx_city_country_age ON table (city_id, country_id, age)`

Comment: I thought about that, but I will need to add more columns and it will likely exceed the 16 column limit for indexes.

Comment: Then stop adding columns to the index. Three or four well-chosen columns should be enough columns to filter the results 99.9%. You may have other terms in your WHERE clause, but they don't all have to be indexed.

Comment: @BillKarwin Most of the "indexes" are foreign keys to other tables. Only a few columns in the table just have standard indexes on them.

Answer (score 0):

You asked what will bring the query time down, and using a composite index will do that. Searching a single composite index is faster than searching several single-column indexes and performing an intersection merge on the results.

You commented that you will be adding more columns in the future, and there will eventually be more than 16 columns.

*You don't have to add ALL the columns to the composite index!*

Index design is not magic. It follows rules. You will create indexes designed to support specific queries that you need to run. You don't add add columns to an index unless they help the given query. You may have multiple composite indexes in the table, created to help different queries.

You might like my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really) (or the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU)).

Re your comment:

> I won't know every possible query combination ahead of time.

Yes, that's true. You can only create indexes for queries that you know. Other queries will not be optimized. If you need to optimize queries in the future, you might need to add new indexes to support them.

In my experience, this happens regularly, and I address this in the presentation. You will review your queries from time to time, because of course your application code changes and the queries you need change. You may add new indexes, or replace an index with a different index, or drop indexes that are no longer needed.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer (and my apologies for not understanding)! I will review your presentation

Comment: Great. Thanks for the additional feedback!